# Docker on Google Compute f1-micro instance

Tags: docker, google-compute-engine, docker-machine

I'm trying to deploy a new docker machine on google compute engine but I don't need too much resources. Just a simple nginx server.

When I run:

```
$ docker-machine create --driver google --google-project my-project-name my-machine-name
```

It works great but creates a `n1-standard-1` *(1 vCPU, 3.75 GB memory)* instance,
But it has way more resources then I need.
I was also able to create a `g1-small` *(1 vCPU, 1.7 GB memory)* instance successfully.
But when i try to create the smallest instance `f1-micro` *(1 vCPU, 0.6 GB memory)* it get's stuck on `Installing docker`

I'm using the command:

```
$ docker-machine create --driver google --google-project my-project-name --google-machine-type f1-micro my-machine-name
```

Console output:

```
Running pre-create checks...
(my-machine-name) Check that the project exists
(my-machine-name) Check if the instance already exists
Creating machine...
(my-machine-name) Generating SSH Key
(my-machine-name) Creating host...
(my-machine-name) Opening firewall ports
(my-machine-name) Creating instance
(my-machine-name) Waiting for Instance
(my-machine-name) Uploading SSH Key
Waiting for machine to be running, this may take a few minutes...
Detecting operating system of created instance...
Waiting for SSH to be available...
Detecting the provisioner...
Provisioning with ubuntu(systemd)...
Installing Docker...
```

Is there a minimum requirement for a docker machine? Because I looked and was not able to find it.
from what I saw in the examples on the [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/machine/drivers/gce/) it should be possible:

```
$ gcloud auth login
$ docker-machine create --driver google --google-project PROJECT_ID vm01
$ docker-machine create --driver google \
  --google-project PROJECT_ID \
  --google-zone us-central1-a \
  --google-machine-type f1-micro \
  vm02
```

Am i missing anything?
Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok it ended up working it just took a VERY long time.

**15-20 minutes** in my case. (3 different machines)